# How can I make my email show only one time per email?

Tags: python, email, while-loop, imap, python-2.x

I've been making a Python script which checks for emails since logging in. Here is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import imaplib, getpass

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
u = raw_input('Your Gmail Address: ')
p = getpass.getpass()
mail.login(u, p)
mail.select("inbox")

while 1:
        r, data = mail.search(None, "ALL")
        ids = data[0]
        id_list = ids.split()
        latest_email_id = id_list[-1]
        r, data = mail.fetch(latest_email_id, "(RFC822)")
        raw_email = data[0][1]
        print raw_email
```

The problem is that it keeps showing the same email over and over again (until a new one is received) because of the `while` loop.

How can I make it:

1. Only show a received email once until a new one is received
2. Only show the new one once
3. Repeat forever

Comment: You need to save the IDs of all the messages that you've shown previously. Then go through the list and skip any that are in the saved list.

Comment: @Barmar Could you explain that? I'm new to `imaplib`.

Comment: It's just basic Python data structures. Use a `set` to hold all the IDs that you've seen. Then do `for id in id_list:` to loop over all the IDs, test if they're in the set. If it's not in the set, print the email and add the ID to the set.

Comment: Nothing special about `imaplib` there. You already know how to get all the IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution:

```
list = []

while 1:
        mail.select('inbox')
        r, data = mail.search(None, "ALL")
        ids = data[0]
        id_list = ids.split()
        latest_email_id = id_list[-1]
        r, data = mail.fetch(latest_email_id, "(RFC822)")
        raw_email = data[0][1]
        if not raw_email in list:
                print raw_email
                list.append(raw_email)
```

Basically, it creates a list called `list`:

```
list = []
```

And then, in the loop it is mostly the same, except in the beginning, it checks the mailbox again:

```
while 1:
    mail.select('inbox')
```

And then, at the end, it will `print` `raw_email` if it is `not` in the `list` and then adds it to the `list` so it will not be `print`ed again:

```
if not raw_email in list:
                print raw_email
                list.append(raw_email)
```

Comment: Also getting error ** latest_email_id = id_list[-1]
IndexError: list index out of range**while using the above code.

Answer (score 1):

So you basically want to develop an *email listener*...
In the following code, I'll just download the unseen emails, so that we have just the relevant data. Then, once an email is fetched, I mark it as 'read' so it's id won't turn up again:

```
while 1:
        r, search_data = mail.search(None, "UNSEEN") #gets only the unseen emails
        ids = data[0]
        id_list = ids.split()
        latest_email_id = id_list[-1]
        r, data = mail.fetch(latest_email_id, "(RFC822)")
        raw_email = data[0][1]
        print raw_email
        mail.store(search_data[0].replace(' ',','),'+FLAGS','\Seen') #marks as read
```

Now, at least your code won't print the same email again and again. `IMAP` is generally more reliable than `POP3` in getting new emails quickly. Still, it can take some time.

Comment: What if two (or more) emails arrive between iterations? This will show the newest, but skip the others.

Comment: @Barmar you're right. But I think there's an IMAP function which returns only the "unread" emails. However, for it to realise that we've "read" the email, a logout is probably needed. So I think login and logouts should also be repeated. I'll modify my code.

Comment: @SamChats `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'`

Comment: @LeagueOfGamers Sorry for the mistake. I've corrected the answer. Do try again and let me know.

Comment: @SamChats     `latest_email_id = id_list[-1]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @KeeganKuhn is your `ids` an empty string?

Comment: @SamChats : **latest_email_id = id_list[-1]
IndexError: list index out of range** getting this error,

Comment: @SamChats : **Even i have used **id_list = []**